# Integral with triangular functions in exponential and numerator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to find the solution of an integral with a triangular function in the numerator and in an exponential, but after an hour Mathematica has not given me an answer. I wondered if there is a method to make it easier for Mathematica to take this integral.

I have already done whatever simplification that I could think of. The following is the integral I am trying to calculate. Does anyone have any idea how to take this?

```
        Integrate[
 1/(128 A0^2 l^4) E^((
  l0^2 \[Pi] (-1 - l^2 + (-1 + l^2) Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]))/(4 A0 l))
   l0 (8 A0 l^2 (16 A0 l^2 - (-1 + l^2) l0^4 lapl \[Pi]) + 
    l0^3 \[Pi] (8 A0 l^2 (1 + l^2) l0 lapl Cos[2 (t - thetaj)] + 
       dxl^2 l0 Cos[
         t]^2 (1 - 
          l^2 + (1 + l^2) Cos[
            2 (t - thetaj)]) (-8 A0 l - (-1 + l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] + (1 + 
             l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]) + 
       16 A0 dyl l^2 (1 - l^2 + (1 + l^2) Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]) Sin[
         t] + dyl^2 l0 (1 - 
          l^2 + (1 + l^2) Cos[
            2 (t - thetaj)]) (-8 A0 l - (-1 + l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] + (1 + 
             l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]) Sin[t]^2 + 
       2 Cos[t] (1 - 
          l^2 + (1 + l^2) Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]) (8 A0 dxl l^2 + 
          l0 (8 A0 l (-dxl dyl + dyxl l) - 
             dxl dyl (-1 + l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] + 
             dxl dyl (1 + l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] Cos[2 (t - thetaj)]) Sin[
            t]))), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: There is something wrong in your code, `{t,0,2 Pi}` appears twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have corrected it. @DanielHuber

Comment: even for a much simpler case Assuming[thetaj > 0, 
 Integrate[(
  E^((l0^2 \[Pi] (-1 - l^2 + (-1 + l^2) Cos[2 (tp)]))/(4 A0 l))
    l0 (dxl l0^3 \[Pi] Cos[
      tp + thetaj] (1 - 
       l^2 + (1 + l^2) Cos[2 (tp)]) (dxl l0 Cos[
        tp + thetaj] (-8 A0 l - (-1 + l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] + (1 + 
            l^2) l0^2 \[Pi] Cos[2 (tp)]))))/(
  128 A0^2 l^4), {tp, 0, 2 Pi}]], it cannot find the solution easily. I guess there must be a better way of doing this.